# webrick fails asking another openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed openssl 1.0.1c requirement for rubies 1.8.7 and 1.9.1 and then do rvm reinstall these rubies.
With installation of 1.9.3-p194, when I try to run webrick fails, then prints out this message:

`Exiting`

~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gem193p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/openssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method - ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)h

I've read then to resolve is necessary execute
<kbd>rvm install pkg openssl</kbd>

and then reinstall **all** rubies !!

If I made this *I can lost all patch and modify applied on ruibes 1.8.7 and 1.9.1* 
(patches and modification for debug e openssl) ?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have something like yours.

[RAILS, bundle install returns - undefined symbol: SSLv2_method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759767/rails-bundle-install-returns-undefined-symbol-sslv2-method)

In my case I wrote this link: http://awolf.ru/rails-on-ubuntu-with-rvm/
It is on russian, but commands are simple.