# RAILS, bundle install returns - undefined symbol: SSLv2_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, undefined-symbol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [undefined symbol: SSLv2_method when running bundle install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759518/undefined-symbol-sslv2-method-when-running-bundle-install)

I try "bundle install" my Rails project, but I have this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler 
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks! 
/home/vekozlov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /home/vekozlov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method - /home/vekozlov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
```

I have found this case ( [Ubuntu and undefined symbol for SSLv2_method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206546/undefined-symbol-sslv2-method) ), but I do not understand how to fix it in Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Thanks for any help.

UPD:
It worked for me (on russian)

http://awolf.ru/rails-on-ubuntu-with-rvm/

Comment: If you have found solution then post it as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps to solve the problem:

```
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
$ rvm pkg install zlib
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
$ rvm pkg install readline
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
$ gem install rails
```